# How do I access my Database from HerokuApp?

Tags: database, heroku

I would like access to users from my heroku app, with the following service & plan
SERVICE heroku-postgresql PLAN hobby-dev

I can the number of rows on data.heroku.com/datastore/[project], but don't know how to access it

Thank you!

Comment: When you add a Heroku Postgres Database to your app you will have a new environment variable set in your app called `DATABASE_URL`. Using that URL you connect to it just like any other Postgres Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your database URL in the Settings tab for your application. Click the button *Reveal Environment Variables* and look for the DATABASE_URL variable. You can use this URL to connect to your database using regular Postgres DBMS.

Another option is to install [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and then run the following commands:

```
heroku login
heroku pg:psql -a APPNAME
```

Replace `APPNAME` with the name of your application and this will connect you to the default database for that application, allowing you to execute queries from command line.